# How to sort custom Type by String

Tags: list, sorting, haskell

How can I sort animals by their name? Names are represented by `String` values.

```
data Animal = Cat String | Dog String | Fox String deriving (Show)

testAnimals = [(Dog "c"),(Fox "a"),(Cat "b")]

sortAnimalsByName :: [Animal] -> [Animal]
sortAnimalsByName animals = undefined
```

The query:

```
sortAnimalsByName testAnimals
```

should return:

```
[(Fox "a"),(Cat "b"),(Dog "c")]
```

I think the function `sort :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]` from `Data.List` should be used, but how?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First you better define an `animalName` function:

```
animalName :: Animal -> String
animalName (Cat n) = n
animalName (Dog n) = n
animalName (Fox n) = n
```

Simply use [`sortBy`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:sortBy) where the comparator is simply [`compare`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:compare) but [`on`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-Function.html#v:on) the `animalName`:

```
import Data.Function(on)
import Data.List(sortBy)

sortAnimalsByName :: [Animal] -> [Animal]
sortAnimalsByName = sortBy (compare `on` animalName)
```

Or you can - like @JonPurdy suggests, use `comparing` which is basically the same as `on compare`:

```
import Data.Ord(comparing)

sortAnimalsByName :: [Animal] -> [Animal]
sortAnimalsByName = sortBy (comparing animalName)
```

or even shorter:

```
import Data.List(sortOn)

sortAnimalsByName :: [Animal] -> [Animal]
sortAnimalsByName = sortOn animalName
```

You can furthermore omit the definition of `animalName` if you use [*record-syntax*](http://learnyouahaskell.com/making-our-own-types-and-typeclasses#record-syntax):

```
--omitting the `animalName` function
data Animal = Cat { animalName :: String} |
              Dog { animalName :: String} |
              Fox { animalName :: String} deriving (Show)
```

Comment: ``(compare `on` f)`` = `Data.Ord.comparing f`; `sortBy (comparing f)` = `Data.List.sortOn f`

Comment: @JonPurdy: I've updated the answer with your suggestions, many thanks.

Answer (score 3):

*Edited* Thank you @WillemVanOnsem for your comment.

First of all this should be a proper sum type so that you can avoid repeating String all over. Meaning, you should make it

`type Animal a = Dog a | Cat a | Fox a`

This way you would have a more general Animal type (which is a good thing). One of the advantages of a more general type would be it would allow you to create more precise typeclass instances of Animal.

However in your case the easiest way would be to derive `Show`, `Eq`, and then write an Ord instance like so:

```
data Animal = Cat String | Dog String | Fox String deriving (Show, Eq)

instance Ord Animal where
  (Cat x) `compare` (Cat y) = x `compare` y
  (Cat x) `compare` (Dog y) = x `compare` y
  (Cat x) `compare` (Fox y) = x `compare` y
  (Dog x) `compare` (Cat y) = x `compare` y
  (Dog x) `compare` (Dog y) = x `compare` y
  (Dog x) `compare` (Fox y) = x `compare` y
  (Fox x) `compare` (Cat y) = x `compare` y
  (Fox x) `compare` (Dog y) = x `compare` y
  (Fox x) `compare` (Fox y) = x `compare` y
```

or

```
data Animal a = Cat a | Dog a | Fox a deriving (Show, Eq)

instance Ord a => Ord (Animal a) where
  (Cat x) `compare` (Cat y) = x `compare` y
  (Cat x) `compare` (Dog y) = x `compare` y
  (Cat x) `compare` (Fox y) = x `compare` y
  (Dog x) `compare` (Cat y) = x `compare` y
  (Dog x) `compare` (Dog y) = x `compare` y
  (Dog x) `compare` (Fox y) = x `compare` y
  (Fox x) `compare` (Cat y) = x `compare` y
  (Fox x) `compare` (Dog y) = x `compare` y
  (Fox x) `compare` (Fox y) = x `compare` y
```

You can use `sort` because now `Animal` has an `Ord` instance

```
-- sort :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]

sort testAnimals
```

Point is: use typeclasses. That is just the easiest way for your simple type.

Comment: This will not sort the objects based on the *name* of the animal. The default `Ord` will always sort a `Cat` lower than `Dog` and `Dog` lower than `Fox` (or in your case `Dog` < `Cat` < `Fox`), regardless of their name. In case of a tie, the name will indeed be used. But `Cat "zz"` will be less than `Fox "aa"`. It first sorts on constructor (`Cat`, `Dog`, `Fox`) and then - iirc - on its parameters.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Thank you. I just edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Joining answers, given by @Willem Van Onsem (record-syntax) and @urbanslug (implementing `Ord` class instance) we obtain the simplest one:

```
data Animal a = Cat {name :: a}
              | Dog {name :: a}
              | Fox {name :: a} deriving (Show, Eq)

instance Ord a => Ord (Animal a) where
  a1 `compare` a2 = name a1 `compare` name a2
```

So that it is possible to say simply

```
λ> sort [(Dog "c"),(Fox "a"),(Cat "b")]
[Fox {name = "a"},Cat {name = "b"},Dog {name = "c"}]
```

Using `Data.Ord.comparing` function one coud write even more precisely:

```
instance Ord a => Ord (Animal a) where compare = comparing name
```